# Chief series of a group using a chief series of normal subgroup and its quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. We note that using a composition series for $N$ and $G/N$, one can construct a [composition series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series) for $G$.

**Question:**  Does the same holds for chief series of a group. Formally, can we construct a chief series for $G$ using a [chief series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_series) of $N$ and $G/N$?

I tried to do it as follows:

Let $$ N \trianglelefteq G_{m-1}/N \trianglelefteq  \dots \trianglelefteq  G_1/N   \trianglelefteq  G_{0}/N=G/N$$ be a chief series for $G/N$ and

$$1= N_{t} \trianglelefteq  N_{t-1} \trianglelefteq \dots  \trianglelefteq N_0=N $$  be a chief series of $N$.

**Claim:** The series  $$ 1= N_{t} \trianglelefteq  N_{t-1} \trianglelefteq \dots  \trianglelefteq N_0=N \trianglelefteq G_{m-1} \trianglelefteq  \dots \trianglelefteq  G_1   \trianglelefteq  G_{0}=G$$ is a chief series for $G$.

Now, it is easy to show that the factors $G_i/G_{i+1}$ are minimal normal subgroup of $G/G_{i+1}$ for $$1 \leq i \leq m $$.But I think that the the quotients $N_{i}/N_{i+1}$ may not be normal in $G/N_{i+1}$.

Can someone please help me with the same. I appreciate your efforts. Thank you.

**Edit:** 1. I understand the answer given by Derek Holt. After adding extra information, can we prove the same. If yes, what information we need to add to make such chief series for $G$.

2. I just need to construct a chief series containing a given normal subgroup. (I think Derek Holt's comment answer this.)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in saying that $N_i$ need not be normal in $G$, so the answer to your question is no, you cannot construct a chief series of $G$ from chief series of $N$ and of $G/N$.

An easy example is $A_4$ with $|N|=4$. In fact $1 < N < A_4$ is a chief series of $G$, but a chief series of $N$ has an extra subgroup of order $2$, which is not normal in $G$, so if I just told you a chief series of $N$ and of $G/N$ without any extra information about $G$, then you would not be able to construct a chief series of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is it even possible after adding extra information ? (I have edited the questions).

Comment: You need to know the conjugation action of $G$ on $N$. Then you can compute a chief series of $G$ that includes $N$ and the inverse images in $G$ of the chief series of $G/N$. But in that case you are not really using your given chief series of $N$. You cannot in general find a chief series of $G$ which contains a subset of the given chief series of $N$.

Comment: So, that means one can construct a chief series that contains a given normal subgroup. That is enough for me.
Also, if you elaborate in detail how this conjugation action construction works, it will be very helpful. Thank you!